# How to determine distribution of $s_1^2/s_2^2$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared, bivariate-distributions

Let $x_i, y_i , i=1,2,...,n$ be a random sample from a bi-variate normal population $N_2(μ_1,μ_2,σ_1,σ_2,ρ)$. How to find the distribution of $s_1^2/s_2^2$  in  non-null case i.e. when $ρ≠0$

Comment: It is obvious that S1² and S2² will follow chi-square with n-1 degrees of freedom... Please guide how to proceed further

Comment: Please read the description of the tag '[distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)'. It is *not* about probability distributions. There is another tag for such.